# Getting a "Run-time Error '1004'" for my VBA copy and paste macro

Tags: excel, vba

The Run-time Error  '1004' I am receiving shows up in the "SetwkbSource" line just after the "Do While" line (noted in code).

**Here is an exact quote of the error:**

"Rune-time error '1004':

Sorry, we couldn't find
C:\Users\NG\Desktop\CopyPaste\file.xlsm.
Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

*(The file.xlsm is a placeholder for another file outside of the CopyPaste folder I specified)*

```
Sub CopyRange()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\NG\Desktop\CopyPaste\"
    ChDir strPath
    strExtension = Dir("*.xls*")
    Do While strExtension <> ""
        ***'Error in the line below***
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
        With wkbSource
            LastRow = .Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F" & LastRow).Copy wkbDest.Sheets("Zone").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Close savechanges:=False
        End With
        strExtension = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Better to pass the full path to `Dir`  i.e.  `Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx")`

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! `Dir("*.xls*")` is now `Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")`

Comment: `ChDir` is not always reliable, particularly if you have multiple drives

Comment: It seems to be working for both my C: and H: drives. Hopefully it continues to work for different drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what the issue was with the help of another individual who has commented above. A working solution is to replace `strExtension = Dir("*.xls*")` with `strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")`.